# String Array Equated to a Cursor.getstring() gives me NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, android

This is my code from my android project where i would want to store each string element from the cursor to a string array, but i keep getting `NullPointer` Exception.

The Code is Down Below, `series2Strings[]` is the string array i have defined,

```
int k=0;
        if(cur.moveToFirst()){
            while(!cur.isAfterLast()){

                Log.i("String", " "+ k + " " + cur.getString(1));
                series2Strings[k]=cur.getString(1);
                k++;
                cur.moveToNext();
            }
        }


        cur.close();
```

The data is available at the cursor because i have checked it in the logcat by using the log statement. Can anyone please point what's going wrong.

Comment: maybe your array `series2Strings` is not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your string array first..

```
series2Strings = new String[cur.getCount()];
int k=0;
if(cur.moveToFirst()){
    while(!cur.isAfterLast()){

      Log.i("String", " "+ k + " " + cur.getString(1));
       series2Strings[k]=cur.getString(1);
        k++;
         cur.moveToNext();
       }
 }
 cur.close();
```

Comment: I've got the output in the `logcat`, but just after it comes out of the loop it goes into `NullPointerException` and the app closes. Should i use `try/catch` or is there any recification.

Comment: I got it, could able to remove the `NullPointerException` by adding a `if` inside the `while` loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
final int length = cur.getCount();
series2Strings = new series2Strings[length];
```